# Matplotlib axis not displayed

Tags: python, matplotlib

The python code (python 2.7) running on windows 7 shown below results in the following inconsistent behaviour with respect to the display of axis which I do not understand:

1 - a window is opened and a plot without an axis is displayed showing a point
2 - on closing the window, another window is opened and a plot is displayed showing the same point but this time with an axis.

```
from osgeo import ogr
import pylab
from ospybook.vectorplotter import VectorPlotter

vp = VectorPlotter(False)

myLoc = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)

myLoc.AddPoint(59.5,13)
vp.plot(myLoc,'rs')
pylab.show() ## the plot is displayed --without-- axes displayed

myLoc.AddPoint(59.5,13)
vp.plot(myLoc,'rs')
pylab.show() ## the plot is displayed with axes displayed
```

Please note that in my environment, if the vector plotter interactive mode is set to True, pylab.show() opens  window but no plot is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
vp = VectorPlotter(interactive=False, ticks=True)
```

Comment: That sorted it. Many thanks!  Question I must ask is why with my original code did the ticks only appear the second time the window was created and plot displayed?